# How can I calibrate contrast on my laptop screen on Windows 10 without external controllers?

Tags: windows-10, laptop, display, display-settings, calibration

I recently noted that photos edited on my computer look very different on my mobile phone. I thus concluded that I might want to calibrate my laptop screen.

There is a built-in calibration tool in Windows 10 which is very useful for some basic adjustments (You don't need external references as there are instructions such as "Try to minimize the visibility of the small circles" for gamma). However, for adjusting brightness and contrast, one is told to use the controllers/buttons etc. on your monitor.

Since I work on a laptop, I do not have such a system. I *can* adjust brightness using keyboard combinations, but the same is not possible for contrast.

So: Is there anything I can so to adjust my laptop's screen contrast without external calibration devices? There are, as far as I could tell, no such settings.

---

In case it might be relevent, here are some specs:

- Laptop: Acer Aspire E 17 (E5-774G-71AH)
- Windows 10 Home 1909 (64-bit Version)

If anything important is missing, just tell me in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Your device uses the `Intel HD Graphics 620` chipset.

You'll therefore want to install Intel® Graphics Control Panel which you can obtain from https://www.intel.co.uk/content/www/uk/en/support/articles/000055711/graphics.html

If that tool doesn't give you the additional settings you wish to change, you might be limited by the graphics device and/or display panel.